# Основные правила рассылки на PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! Нужно написать скрипт по рассылке php. Возникли ряд вопросов.

1) При нажатии на кнопку рассылвать, будет производиться рассылка всем клиентам. Буду брать БД клиентов, прогонять через цикл и каждому отсылать. Верно ли это?

2) Хостинг говорит что можно рассылать 500 писем в час, как поставить задержку на PHP что я могу высылать 500 писем, потом ждать час и продолжать рассылку?

3) Какие еще правила должны учитываться при создании модуля рассылки?

Answer (score 1):

Рассылка через базу не совсем хорошее решение... Это лишняя нагрузка на базу, а следовательно падение производительности, отсутствие тайм-аутов на выполнение задачи (нужно писать свой костыль), не расширяемость и т.д. По сути отправляя через базу вы пишете просто **свою самописную очередь** на реляционном хранилище, но зачем писать велосипед, когда он уже написан? :)

Правильное решение - это использовать очередь сообщений (задач). Они придуманы для того, чтобы заниматься следующими задачами:

- отложенная обработка пользовательских данных;
- передача статистики;
- сглаживание нагрузки на относительно медленные системы;
- выполнение периодических задач.

Плюсы данного решения:

- Отправка писем универсальна с любого компонента системы, пусть то форма регистрации или ваша рассылка. Представьте как круто, у Вас один интерфейс на отправку, и вы просто отправляете задачу откуда угодно не прибегая к подключению библиотеки на отправку писем.
- Расширяемость - вы можете добавить абсолютно любой канал рассылки просто добавил поле тип (смс, звонок, письмо, почта России) и поддержав его в обработчиках.
- Время добавления задачи всегда моментально для клиента добавляющего сообщение в очередь.
- Возможность ускорить отправку писем просто добавив еще несколько Worker'ов
- Надежность - добавленные сообщения в очередь не пропадут (если так настроено), и задача будет считаться выполненной только когда скрипт скажет что все окей. Чтобы уберечься от отвала демона очереди можно развернуть кластер.
- Относительно быстрая интеграция в архитектуру

У вас есть Publisher публикующий сообщение в очередь о том, что нужно отправить письмо такому-то адресату, с таким-то текстом, далее есть консьюмеры (воркеры) которые берут эти задачи из очереди и отсылают письма клиентам. Если косьюмер упал, не смог отправить, он просто возвращает задачу в очередь обратно и ее возьмет другой консьюмер который попробует ее отправить.

В плане архитектуры думаю разобрались, далее перейдем к тому как обойти ограничение на хостинге и отправлять письма. Если вы хотите отправлять большие объемы - то можно использовать сервис отправки писем с API, например [Mailgun](https://mailgun.com), который позволяет бесплатно отправлять 10000 писем в месяц, хотя возможно для Вас это все таки мало..

Есть сервисы которые занимаются чисто рассылками - например [unisender](http://unisender.com) - **можете даже тогда ничего не писать**, а просто загружать туда базу своих emailов и отправлять им письма.

Чтобы ограничить кол-во передаваемых сообщений используйте какое-то хранилище для хранения количества. Можете создать таблицу в базе данных и писать **атомарной** операцией в нее, сколько писем было отправлено за текущий час и при превышении интервала прекращать отправку.  Вы можете добавить кейс, о том что если в основном канале доставки кончился лимит - отправляем через вторичный.

Я бы рекомендовал Вам перейти с обычного хостинга на какой-нибудь VPS для решения подобных задач, за счет возможности собственного администрирования и **отсутствия ограничений** на отправку писем.

Comment: Как создать такую очередь совместно с php

Comment: @5f0f5048ff Легко, очередь например, можно использовать RabbitMQ, и драйвер php-amqp :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Сделайте кнопку «Разослать» и сделайте страницу с просмотром статистики — на которой будет указано количество отосланных сообщений и кнопка «Отправить ещё» и в ручную отправлять дальше сообщения.

2) Задайте в выборке из базы Количество выбираемых записей — в вашем случае это 500 (если конечно ещё какие то сообщения не отправляются). И по 500 выбирайте и при следующих «досылках» используйте смещение в выборке.

3) Проверяйте что Вам возвращает функция mail() и либо записывайте куда то либо просто следите что бы сообщения уходили и прерывайте отправку если возникло несколько ошибок подряд.

Answer (score 0):

1. При нажатии на кнопку "Разослать" записывайте все сообщения в отдельную таблицу со статусом NEW
2. Напишите консольный скрипт, который будет отправлять сообщения, которые будет брать из таблицы, в которую записывались сообщения выше. При успешной отправке менять статус сообщения на 'OK", при ошибке 'ERROR'. При обновлении записи должна меняться дата обновления для подсчета отправленных сообщений за час.
3. Запускайте консольный скрипт по крону, получайте список сообщений. SQL запросом можно получить количество сообщений, отправленных за последний час. Исходя из этого количества можно определить, сколько сообщений можно отправить. Нужно понимать, попадает ли в лимит 500 в час сообщение, которое не удалось отправить. Проверяйте email на валидность перед отправкой.

Answer (score 0):

Коллеги уже дали несколько годных советы по организации рассылки своими силами. Но я бы посоветовал использовать готовые сервисы отправки почты. Помимо удобных интерфейсов они имеют массу настроек и дополнительных возможностей вроде отслеживания доставки, автоматического учета отлупов и т.д.

Хороший обзор сервисов есть тут: https://habrahabr.ru/post/280634/

Соответственно, от вашего модуля рассылки требуется только реализовать клиентскую часть API. Как правило, вызывать можно синхронно, если в руководстве не сказано иначе. Если место критичное, то вызовы делать отложенно или отправлять пачками по мере поступления новых писем.